# Using str_replace to make hundreds of spelling corrections

Tags: r, tidyverse, str-replace

I'm looking for a more efficient way of replacing *lots* of strings. I'm essentially running a manual spell check across my entire df, where incorrectly spelled responses / typos are corrected:

```
df <- df %>%
            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "^anker$", "anchor"))) %>%
            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "^baloon$", "balloon"))) %>%
            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "^celeary$", "celery"))) %>%
            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "^dear$", "deer")))
```

This works great, and I've done the tedious job of finding everything I want to change, but having the same line of code copy and pasted like this (for hundreds of corrections) isn't pretty. Is there a way I can feed a df into str_replace to get a similar results? I was thinking something like this:

```
"Spell_check_df" that looks like this:

   responses     correction
---------------------------
1. ^anker$       anchor       
2. ^baloon$      balloon
3. ^celeary$     celery
4. ^dear$        deer


df <- df %>%
            mutate_all(funs(str_replace(Spell_check_df, responses, correction)))
```

Any help would be appreciated - I just can't seem to get it working. Obviously I want the responses and corrections to be *tied* together.

Comment: Can you please add a sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
spell_check_vec <- Spell_check_df$correction
names(spell_check_vec) <- Spell_check_df$responses
str_replace_all(.,spell_check_vec)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why your code would solve the problem.